# Internal 500 error on Elastic Beanstalk with plotly dash app

Tags: python, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, plotly-dash

I have created a visualization dashboard on dash by `plotly`. It is running perfectly on local server.

But when I am uploading it on elastic beanstalk, it is showing an internal 500 error, see below

[image: This is the error which is showing up.]

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYt8K.png)

Comment: Do you have any logs? Pretty hard to know what happen with this less infos…

Comment: I have added the logs, can you please take a look at them ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still looking for solutions, here is how your `application.py` should be setup

```
import dash

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
application = app.server
.
. # your stuff ... 
.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=True)
```